# Ошибка пагинации Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, пагинация

Возникла ошибка с пагинацией Wordpress. Раньше все работало, подозреваю что дело в обновлении ядра WP. Ошибка заключается в следующем:
На страницах ?page=* в адресной строке работала отлично,а теперь перестала и работает только /page/*.
Тем не менее в категориях ?page=* работает как и прежде, а /page/* наоборот не работает.
Подскажите куда копать, и как вернуть работоспособность пагинации?

Comment: https://wp-punk.com/ne-zabujte-s-vashej-paginatsiej/

Comment: @WPPunk респект за заголовок поста :)